# Возведение в натуральное число

Tags: javascript

Всем ку.
Что означает  x*pow(x,n-1), а именно, **что значит n-1**

Пожалуйста, не могли бы вы объяснить простыми  словами

Где-то я видел, умножение числа на само себя, где использовали **оператор -**,

но не могу вспомнить где и как назывался этот термин.

Я пометил интересующую меня строку

```js
function pow(x, n) {
  if (n == 1) {
    return x;
  } else {
    return x * pow(x, n - 1); // Метка
  }
}

alert( pow(3, 3) );
```

Answer (score -1):

это моими словами
это рекурсия) смотри функция pow вызывает саму себя же внутри с (n-1) до того момента когда n не станет равным 1 и тогда последняя функция вернет x и пойдет обратный порядок каждая вызванная функция pow будет возвращать x* .... пока не завершится последний вызов , то есть `3*3*3`

вот тут подробнее https://learn.javascript.ru/recursion